# Delaunay + Kruskal unknown zero point

Tags: boost, cgal

I've got a strange behaviour when reading edges after applying Kruskal algo on a delaunay graph. When displaying the result edges, sometimes one point of some edge can be a point (always (0,0)) which hadn't been added in the graph points. Does someone know where that comes from?

```
for (i = 0; i < Max; i++)
{
    vertices.push_back(m_boostVector(data[i].x, data.y));
}
dt.insert(vertices.begin(), vertices.end());

for (index = 0, boost::tie(vit, ve) = boost::vertices(ft); vit != ve; vit++, index++)
{
    vertex_id_map[*vit] = index;
}

boost::kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(dt, std::back_inserter(mst), vertex_index_map(vertex_index_pmap));

for (std::list<edge_descriptor>::iterator it = mst.begin(); it != mst.end(); it++)
{
    Delaunay::Vertex_handle sv = boost::source(*it, ft);
    Delaunay::Vertex_handle tv = boost::target(*it, ft);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't filtered infinite edges, then you might end up accessing the infinite vertex. See the following [section](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/index.html#BGLTriangulations) that contains an example showing how to do it.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

Thanks for the return, in fact I'm already using the finite stuff you mentioned as in the example. And the point on the edge that isn't supposed to be there is always (0,0).

Comment: Just to be sure could you check whether the vertex is not the infinite vertex? You can do that by calling `dt.is_infinite(vh)` where `vh` is the vertex being `(0,0)`

Comment: Tha's it, the "zero point" is the infinite point. I have a filtered finite delaunay graph, but applied the Kruskal algo on the non-filtered one.

Thanks for your help.